# Javascript Firefox RadialGradient

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas

For my hobby game project we (with friend) use the HTML + JS. And draw on a canvas. We draw a balloons with this kind of code:

```
var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(this.p.x - this.radius / 4, this.p.y - this.radius / 4, this.radius, this.p.x - this.radius / 2, this.p.y - this.radius / 2, 0);
        radGrad.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)");
        radGrad.addColorStop(0, this.color);
        ctx.fillStyle = radGrad;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.p.x, this.p.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
```

In Safari and Chrome we got normal behaviour. Also it is normal in Firefox on Mac OS. But for Firefox on Windows we got:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5283279/Screenshots/2013-04-26%2013_10_26-BalloonSucker.png

When I turn off the hardware acceleration in Firefox - all is working, but this is for public, so I can't recommend others to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it solved. In firefox, when the inner gradient circle is beyound the outer. To fix it:

```
var cInner = [ this.p.x - this.radius / 4, this.p.y - this.radius / 4, this.radius ],
cOuter = [ this.p.x - this.radius / 2, this.p.y - this.radius / 2, 0 ];

var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    cOuter[0],cOuter[1],cOuter[2],
    cInner[0],cInner[1],cInner[2]
);
radGrad.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)");
radGrad.addColorStop(1, this.color);
```